# Deploy/Update WebExtension Firefox/Chrome

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an extension that do the same on Firefox and Chrome that I would like to deploy / be able to update in Enterprise environment for Firefox and Chrome.

I am not wanting to use the stores and I could not find informations on how I would be able to deploy/update this extension on 200+ computers without having to do it manually.

If someone have some informations about how to do this.

Comment: Your question states Firefox & Chrome, but you've only used tags for Firefox. Are you asking about both, or only Firefox? Frankly, I would suggest having two separate questions: one for Firefox and the other for Chrome, as the process will likely be quite different. Note, that even if you do have two separate questions, it's not unlikely that the question will be too broad/unclear just for Firefox. One reason is that it's unclear if you want this to happen as a push or if you want this to happen as a pull. It's also unclear why you are not having this happen though the normal update process.

Comment: Also, are you asking how to have a *new* install be placed on each computer, or are you asking how to *update* an already existing installation of an add-on, or both?

Comment: It is for both Chrome and Firefox. I think it would be as a "push", after the moment I upload my updated extension, it would trigger an update of the extension. I am not using normal process because it is on an Enterprise environment on which it would be too complicated to get/remove each computer on which the update has to be done.

Comment: Enterprise environment does not inherently imply lack of internet connectivity, which is what is implied by your comment about it being "...too complicated to get/remove each computer...". Both Chrome and Firefox have normal methods which are used for their browsers to pull for extension updates. Please explain which requirement you have that prevents using those methodologies.